# Repetitive actions in future tenses: "I will visit" or "I will be visiting"

Tags: grammar, future-constructions

Which form is correct?
"I will visit you regularly."
or
"I will be visiting you regularly."

Comment: They are both correct, and they mean essentially the same thing.

Comment: In English, if you use a time/frequency word like "regularly" in a sentence, it typically doesn't matter whether you use a verb form that indicates frequent/repeated action or a plain form. You certainly don't have to use the future continuous.

Comment: They don't mean exactly the same thing; just like simple present and present progressive do not mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these are correct.

With the verb "visit", the continuous tense adds a sense of an extended (but temporary) stay in each visit.  But the default form would be "will visit".  This form you would use, unless you specifically want to mention the fact that each visit will be extended in time.

Answer (score 0):

COMPARE:

**I'm visiting** you this/next week, aren't I?
And
I'm sure **I'll be visiting you in the future**, right?

Can you see how the present progressive can become the future progressive?
The focus is on the **action of visiting**.

TO:
**I visit** you every time you ask me to. [present simple, habitual action, statement]
**I will visit** you every time you ask me to. [intention of habitual action in the future]

*The focus is on the fact of visiting, not the action involved in it.*

[The word *regularly* can be used without changing the demonstration.]

By trying to feel the difference between the progressive tense, the simple present tense and the future progressive and will+ verb is the way to see how these differ from one another.

Another example:
I'm playing soccer with my son this afternoon.
I'll be playing soccer with my son every Sunday.
I play soccer with my son quite a bit.
I will play soccer with him whenever we both have time play.